# how to apply a softer sharpness in java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, filter, convolution

I know how to improve the sharpness of an image thanks to this javascript code.
But the result is too steep for me.
Would you know how to apply a softer sharpness, with a sharpness factor for instance?

In fact I would like to understand how this sharpness operates through this kernel

```
ScreenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2));
float[]  data = [-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1];
Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
BufferedImageOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
bufferedImage = convolve.filter(ScreenCapture, null); 
File file = new File(imagetemp);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", file);
```

This kernel seems softer, but this is still too :

```
float[]  data= [0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 5.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f ];
```

Thank you for your attention

[original in pdf print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK83q.png)

[screen capture sharpen result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsxdP.png)

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

A **convolution kernel** operates on the pixel and its surrounding pixels. Given a weight matrix (whose center is the pixel), it calculates a weighted sum of the pixel and surrounding pixels.

With a 3x3 matrix, the 9 kernel values are the weights for *upper-left, upper, upper-right, left, center (the target pixel itself), right, lower-left, lower, lower-right* pixels.
The original kernel suggests that the original pixel is multiplied by 9 and all surrounding pixels are substracted (-1), thus boosting the pixel's sharpness.

#### What you are looking for is a similar kernel, which doesn't boost as much.

The **neutral kernel** would be `[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` (target pixel = source pixel), so you can **blend your kernel with the neutral kernel** by any factor you like.

A **half-sharp kernel** would be `[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,4.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]` (sum of the halves of each kernel).

Note that the kernel is **normalized**: the sum of the weights is always 1: if it were different, the image would get brighter (>1) or darker (<1).

Comment: hello Peter
on the basis of your proposal, I looked for a reduction factor observed and  then adjusted the result to achieve the same characteristics of the image (color and brightness). This gives the following progression:
float[] data =  [-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1  ]
float[]  data= [-0.5,-0.5, -0.5,-0.5,4,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0.5];
float[] data =  [-0.25,-0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 3,-0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25  ]
float[] data =  [-0.175,-0.175, -0.175, -0.175, 2.4,-0.175, -0.175, -0.175, -0.175  ]
float[] data =  [-0.0875,-0.0875, -0.0875, -0.0875, 1.7,-0.0875, -0.0875, -0.0875, -0.0875  ]

Comment: I fail to grasp the logic of the progression of the central pixel
9,4,3,2.4,1.7

Comment: that's it, I understood the progression
8n + 1
Thanks a lot ;)